# HDFS start-all.sh by root or non-root user

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am learning Hadoop, and would like to try the pseudo-distributed operation

When I try to use `start-all.sh` to start the Hadoop daemons, should I use a non-root user like foo-user or use root.

Using root has no problem, however, I am a little bit concerned about it.

Using a non-root user, foo-user, it complains that it doesn't have permission to files

```
/var/run/hadoop/hadoop-foo-user-namenode.pid: permission denied
/var/run/hadoop/hadoop-foo-user-tasktracker-foohost.pid: permission denied
```

It was trying to create these two files in the directory `/var/run/hadoop`

I tried `vim /var/run/hadoop/testfile`, and couldn't save. So turns out that foo-user doesn't have permission to write at `/var/run/hadoop`

I checked the permission of `/var/run/hadoop`

```
drwxrwxr-x root hadoop 4096 Feb 8 23:42 hadoop
```

foo-user is in group hadoop, so should have write permission to `/var/run/hadoop`. Indeed, several other id files are created there, like the ...jobtracker.pid

So should I use root for `start-all.sh` or there is something wrong with the permission ( I am really confused)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to start Hadoop as the root, below is quoted from Yahoo's Hadoop tutorial:

> The user who owns the Hadoop instances will need to have read and
>   write access to each of these directories. It is not necessary for all
>   users to have access to these directories. Set permissions with chmod
>   as appropriate. In a large-scale environment, it is recommended that
>   you create a user named "hadoop" on each node for the express purpose
>   of owning and running Hadoop tasks. For a single individual's machine,
>   it is perfectly acceptable to run Hadoop under your own username. It
>   is not recommended that you run Hadoop as root.

Even though `foo-user` is in the group `hadoop` in the Linux filesystem, you still need to make sure 
 that `foo-user` is also a group member in HDFS (by default the group is called `supergroup`), you'll see what the group is when you do `hadoop fs -ls path_to_your_data`.

Answer (score 0):

group as well as user needs to be hadoop. Here you have:

```
drwxrwxr-x root hadoop 4096 Feb 8 23:42 hadoop
```

so change the root into hadoop (curently i don't have access to any linux machine so I can't say exact commands), then make yourself sure that hadoop user is able to create filies and directories within `/var/run/hadoop`. I strongly recommend to run it s non-root user.